# How to overwriter ShapeMarkerFactory In GeoServer?

Tags: java, geoserver, geotools

I want to create a new Mark in GeoServer's SLD style, but I can't find MarkFactory interface in GeoServer sources code, and I can't find the ShapeMarkFactory class in these code. I don't know where can I add the Geotool class in GeoServer's source code and make it work, or where I can overwriter the ShapeMarkFactory class to add a new WellKnowName Mark In Mark.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a new factory to GeoServer rather than try to modify the existing one.

There is a [Factory tutorial for GeoTools](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/factory.html) (which is what does the work in GeoServer) which will show the basic principal for creating a factory and using the SPI system to register it with GeoTools applications like GeoServer.

Once you have written your new factory which can either extend [`ShapeMarkFactory`](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/main/modules/library/render/src/main/java/org/geotools/renderer/style/ShapeMarkFactory.java) or implement [`MarkFactory`](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/main/modules/library/render/src/main/java/org/geotools/renderer/style/MarkFactory.java#L25) if you want a different prefix to trigger it. You'll need a file called `META-INF/services/org.geotools.renderer.style.MarkFactory` (in the resources folder of your project) that file should contain a line with the fully qualified name of your factory.

Then you can use `mvn` to compile the project into a jar file or a zip including any necessary external jars. You can then add those jars to the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your GeoServer install and restart it.